# How to static_cast to the type of variable

Tags: c++, c++11, types, casting, c++14

If I have a variable or member of a known type is there a method that I can static cast to said type without expressly stating the type?

Thus ensuring that should the variable change type in the future a re-compilation will be all that's needed.

A very basic example would be:

```
int y = 5;
uint32_t x;
x = static_cast< TYPEOF( x ) >( foo );
```

Now if at some point in the future x needed to change to an int64_t say it would be nice if only the declaration of the variable needed changed and not all the static_cast lines, of which there may be many.

As a personal note, I am compiling with g++ 6 and thus I am able to use c++14 features, though an answer compatible with other versions may benefit others.

Comment: Use `decltype`?

Comment: Do you want `decltype(x)` instead of `TYPEOF` ?

Comment: that is exactly what I want, thank you

Comment: Why do you need that static cast in the first place?

Comment: This is a very basic example of the code I needed this for is highly templated, and though the compiler knows exactly the type of x it is a pain for me to figure this out.

Comment: better leave out the cast. if the type is convertible, it works; if it is a narrowing conversion, you get a warning, if there is no conversion, you get a error.

Comment: And by putting in the cast you tell the compiler that you're happy with the conversion being narrowing.  Which in my use case I want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in the comments above the solution is

```
int y = 5;
uint32_t x;
x = static_cast< decltype( x ) >( y );
```

Answer (score 8):

Simply use `decltype`:

```
x = static_cast<decltype(x)>(y);
```